# Regex for dividing the text within html tags to words

Tags: regex

Does anyone know how to divide text within html tags (h1-h6, a, b, i, br) to "words" using RegEx? For example,

#### input:

```
<h4>TEST</h4> This sentence <br/> is <b><i>test</i></b>
```

#### output:

*Result list of "words":*

```
<h4>TEST</h4>
This
sentence
<br/>
is 
<b> <i>test</i></b>
```

Comment: [Do not parse HTML with Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1583).

Comment: How can I solve this problem not using regex?

Comment: Use an HTML parser for your chosen language/platform.

Comment: It looks like you want a list of individual words, not counting HTML tags. Is the <br/> tag a special case? Are there any others?

Comment: What language are you using? I'm also thinking you'll benefit more from a html parser

Comment: Your question is not well-defined enough; what should happen with `<b>a list <i>of</i> words</b>` ? Is the `<b>` tag to be a singe "word" or should the starting `<b>` tag and the following `a` be a "word" and the ending `</b>` tag and `words` be another word? Also, use a parser.

Comment: <b>a list <i>of</i> words</b> is one "word"

Comment: You are in for a wold of hurt if you try to do this with a regex. Really. [Do not parse HTML with Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1583) is a SO classic, but funny as it is, **it is not a joke**.

Answer (score 0):

I think to do this you'll need to first parse the html with regex which is regex is just not sophisticated enough to do.

I think you'll need to use a parser (in a platform of your choice) in order to complete your project.